# how to access current locale inside model eloquent laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-localization

I have been searching alot for this problem solution. I need to access current app locale set earlier inside my controller function using `\App::setLocale('en')`. But later on i was unable to get current locale inside model using app()->getLocale() or `App::isLocale('en')` or `App::getLocale()`. 
Please Look at below code inside orders model:

```
public function getOrderDetailAttribute($value)
{
    $new = [];
    $arr = json_decode($value,true);
    if(!empty($arr))
    foreach($arr as $val)
    {
       $temp["id"] = $val["id"];

           if(App::isLocale('en'))
               $temp['itemName'] = $val["name"];
           else
               $temp['itemName'] = $val["name_ar"];

       if(!empty($val["size"]))
       $temp['size'] = $val["size"];
       $temp['Qty'] = $val["quantity"];
       $temp['price'] = $val["price"];
       $temp['image'] = $val["p_img_url"];
       $new[] = $temp;
       unset($temp);
    }
    return $new;
}
```

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: provide your code

Comment: can you try Localization::getLocale() or \Localization::getLocale() in your code??? and also try with this localization()->getLocale();